# Draw multiple images on multiple canvas on 1 page html using javascrip

Tags: javascript, c#, html, canvas, drawimage

I found the way to draw multiple image on a canvas
[How to add multiple images to html5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227117/how-to-add-multiple-images-to-html5-canvas)

and the way to draw multiple canvas on a page
[Draw Multiple Canvas on a single page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080086/draw-multiple-canvas-on-a-single-page)

but when I try to draw multiple canvas, each canvas contains multiple images load, it doesn't work.
Only last canvas can load images while the others can not.
Could you please help me solve this problem?
My code is

```
enter code here
var CanvasList = document.getElementsByClassName("listCanvas");
for (var i = 0; i < CanvasList.length; i++) {
    var canvas = CanvasList[i]
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');



    var img_Original = new Image();
    img_Original.src = '../Images/hizume.jpg';
    img_Original.onload = function () {
        canvas.height = img_Original.height;
        canvas.width = img_Original.width;
        ctx.drawImage(img_Original, 0, 0);
    };
```

var strPart = CanvasList[i].id;

```
    do {
        var index = strPart.indexOf(",")
        var partGet = strPart.substring(0, index);
        if (partGet.length == 1) {
            partGet = "0" + partGet;
        }
        var source = "../Images/hizume_" + partGet + "_multi.png";
        var nextImg = new Image();
        nextImg.src = source;
        Img.push(nextImg);
        strPart = strPart.substring(index + 1);

    }
    while (strPart.length > 0);

    partCount = Img.length;
    Img[partCount - 1].onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img_Original, 0, 0);
        for (var j = 0; j < partCount; j++) {
            ctx.drawImage(Img[j], 0, 0);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: why c# tag?????

Comment: I am using C# to create this asp.net mvc project

Comment: Try putting `let ctx = .....`. & `let canvas =`. etc.   Your async code will be loosing scope.

Comment: The `strPart` variable is not defined before it is used.

Comment: @Keith Thank you so much, it work to load images on canvas, but all canvas is the same as last canvas. :( How can I correct it?

Comment: @CoursesWeb: I am sorry, It is missing. var strPart = CanvasList[i].id;

Comment: I change var --> let for some elements than it can work corectly. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Yeah, was just about to say, just change all var's to let's , :)

Comment: The page can be loaded correctly most of time. 
But sometime, after I reload 3-5 times, some or all of canvas not work correctly,
Then I reload some times, it come back to load correctly. 
Could you please explain it to me if you know about it?